# JSP login for 2 pages

Tags: java, jsp, redirect, authentication

I am using JSP and servlets to develop my web application. I have 2 JSP pages which I want to be accessed only after a person logs in.
I want that once a person reaches the page (say page1.jsp) and if they are not logged in they will be asked for username password (on page login.jsp) and once they give correct username password they can go back to the same page(page1.jsp).
And in case they were browsing page2.jsp before, they will be redirected to page2.jsp from login.jsp.

I am not sure how to redirect them to the appropriate page depending on what they were accessing before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the previousURL in the session. Then after the login is successful retrieve the previousURL value from the session and redirect accordingly.

You can get the request URI using [HttpServeltRequest.getRequestURI()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRequestURI%28%29) .To save and retreive values from the session you will need to use the [HttpSession.setAttribute()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#setAttribute%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object%29) to save a value in the session and  [HttpSession.getAttribute()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html#getAttribute%28java.lang.String%29) to get a value from the session. To get the session object itself you can do so by calling [HttpServletRequest.getSession()](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getSession%28%29).

So in a nutshell here are the steps:-

1. In your servlet method for lets say "page1.jsp" you detect that the user is not logged in. Therefore, you store the session variable previousURL.
2. Then you redirect to the login.jsp.
3. After successful login you retrieve the value for previousURL and redirect to that URL from the login servlet.

Hope this helps!